# Remote images don't load in Appcelerator (mobilesdk-1.7.1)

Tags: imageview, titanium, tableview, appcelerator

I have a tabGroup with two tabs:

tab1 and tab2 both have a TableView with some remote images.

If I scroll really fast in tab1 and then quickly change to tab2 before the images can get a change to load and before the momentum scroll has stopped, no images will load in tab2. I have to manually to a little scroll in tab2 before the images will start loading.

Can anyone think of a solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly this is natural on the iPhone, check out a long listing on iTunes in the mobile app and you will see not only does it only load the images you scroll slowly over but also removes them if you scroll a certain number of rows up or down and will reload them when you come back to them. I believe this is a memory saving technique.